# Can JHipster be used to maintain a project, or just initially generate it?

Tags: jhipster

Most information on the web demo generating a JHipster project, don't show a maintenance cycle using the tool. It's rather difficult to find a non-feature if that is the case. Thought I'd ask of those with experience with the tool, and hopefully document the feature or non-feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [upgrade sub-generator](http://www.jhipster.tech/upgrading-an-application/) to upgrade your JHipster app between releases. However, as your app grows and becomes more custom, it might make sense to use JHipster to generate your app, and then upgrade your dependencies as needed.